# Mixed logistic ridge regression

Tags: r

I would like to build a logistic regression model in which I will be looking for predictor variables having a significant effect on the breeding success of a raptor bird.

The predictors in the dataset are highly correlated, which led me to consider logistic ridge regression. Furthermore, I investigated different breeding grounds in which one or multiple birds have been breeding. Since this makes the data clustered, I would need to add the breeding ground as a random effect in the model.

Thus, I would need a 'mixed logistic ridge regression' approach if I am getting things right here. This paper suggests this approach too for another problem:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22049265

Are there any people aware of the availability of an R package or something related having implemented a mixed logistic ridge regression approach as the paper and myself just described? I did not succeed in finding one.

Thank you.

Comment: `library("sos"); findFn("lasso mixed")` and `findFn("ridge mixed")` are pretty good starting points ...

Answer (score 2):

There is an R package named **glmmLasso** that performs variable selection and shrinkage for generalized linear mixed models using the L1 penalty (the Lasso):

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmLasso/index.html

The Lasso isn't the same as ridge regression (which uses the L2 penalty) but will still perform shrinkage of coefficients for correlated variables.

Comment: In addition to the papers referenced in the glmmLasso documentation, there is this 2011 study which incorporates ridge regression with linear mixed effect models (alas not logistic regression): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3202941/. Maybe the same approach could be used with logistic regresion?

Comment: That's correct, Robert. I found the paper too. I also agree this same approach could be used with logistic regression. However, I am afraid that it has not yet been implemented in any R package.

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you want:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ridge/index.html

From the description:

> Linear and logistic ridge regression for small data sets and genome-wide SNP data

Comment: This is not what I need as it cannot incorporate random effects in the model.