# Separate or One Large Multiple Regressions

Tags: mixed-model, regression-strategies

I am investigating the relationship between scores on 3 questionnaires (SPQ,CAPS,PDI) and the effect of an experimental 'Condition' on performance (Correct/Incorrect). I have run the following logistic mixed effects models in lme4 (random effects removed for readability here):

1. Correct ~ PE_Condition*spq
2. Correct ~ PE_Condition*(spq+caps+pdi)

I then ran model 2 with additional covariates, but this did not converge. There is some evidence of multicollinearity between predictors, which has been handled by centering all the predictors.

Currently the SPQ variable is a summary score for the questionnaire. However, this questionnaire can be interpreted differently to generate 3 separate subscale scores. I want to investigate these 3 subscales.

QUESTION: I'm not sure which approach is best to do this:

4. Separately run
   a)Correct ~ PE_Condition*(spq1+caps+pdi)
   b)Correct ~ PE_Condition*(spq2+caps+pdi)
   c)Correct ~ PE_Condition*(spq3+caps+pdi)
5. Correct ~ PE_Condition*(spq1+spq2+spq3+caps+pdi)

Comment: What is the difference between models 2 and 3 ? They seem identical. Can you tell us more about the study design. `spq`, `caps` and `pdi` are separate questionnaires, right ? Where do you see the collinearities ? So far I would agree with Peter about retaining the full dataset

Comment: Apologies; I originally meant to illustrate model 3 as having additional covariates- now corrected above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, unless there are interaction terms or quadratics or cubics etc., centering cannot get rid of collinearity. See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95404/is-centering-a-valid-solution-for-multicollinearity) and, in particular @FrankHarrell 's answer. I'm not sure what happened in your case. (Unless the collinearity is with the intercept, in which case see @CoffeeJunky's answer, but you  say "among the variables).

Second, in general, I think it's better to run one equation. You can deal with collinearity by ridge regression. Ridge regression for multilevel models has also been discussed here a little, e.g. [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118034/mixed-logistic-ridge-regression) but there doesn't seem to be a huge literature on this. Other ways of dealing with colinearity tend to make it hard or impossible to include all the variables, at least, as separate variables, which you say is a goal.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a particular reason that you recommend one model? Second, I conducted centering as I read a few papers which suggested this, particularly for models with interactions between binary and continuous predictors.I indeed do have an interaction between each score and PE_Condition in the equation (e.g., PE_Condition*spq).

Comment: One model because it lets you control for the other variables.  There shouldn't be a correlation between condition and the spq scores. If condition is, as you say, an "experimental condition" then people should be randomly assigned to the different conditions.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. Apologies, I meant the interaction PE_Condition*(spq+pdi+caps). This is when I have problems with (multi)collinearity as the questionnaire scores are correlated.

Comment: Oh. I see. That makes sense. the interactions are colinear is what you are saying, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I found the spq, pdi, caps scores are correlated.